# I'm trying to compare two maps and returning the result in the form of list<String[]> but it's not printing proper result

Tags: java, list, maps

Here is my code:

```
public List compareMaps(Map dataMap1, Map dataMap2) {
    List errData = new ArrayList();

    for (Entry<String, String> data1 : dataMap1.entrySet()) {

        if (dataMap2.containsKey(data1.getKey())) {
            if (!dataMap2.get(data1.getKey()).equalsIgnoreCase(data1.getValue())) {
                errData.add(
                        new String[] { data1.getKey(), data1.getValue(), dataMap2.get(data1.getKey()).toString() });
            }
        } else
            errData.add(
                    new String[] { data1.getKey(), data1.getValue(), "No corresponding data found in paperclip" });

    }

    return errData;
}
```

What could be the issue?

Output:

```
set[[Ljava.lang.String;@3578436e, [Ljava.lang.String;@706a04ae, [
```

Comment: Where is code for displaying output ? Also please edit post with what you want to achieve and what is error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String[] arr:errData){
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.